# how to detect JavaScript root file responsible for some part in site

Tags: javascript

Currently I am designing a site which is template and I would want to delete some part of the javascript in this site, but don`t know the name of the js file which is responsible for particular js effect. Can you please suggest way to remove js with its root file. Thank you!

Comment: you can open up developer tools (firefox/chrome) are the best and then debug your way through and you could use fiddler along with them to give you a better oversight. google on how to use these products to gain better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome you could capture a profile in the timeline, initiate whatever the effect is, then stop the profile and trace the source.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function that is being called to produce the effect, but it could create unexpected results, and is definitely not good practice.

if you have something like `<button onclick="unknownFuncion()">`

then in your script redefine "unknownFuncion"

```
<script>
function unknownFuncion() {
   return this
}
</script>
```